# How to setup a Makefile to compile a C project given some object files and some C files

Tags: c, makefile

I have a C project that contains source code for everything. I would like to give this project to someone to work on only a couple of files in that project. I do not want them to gain access to all the source code in the project, so I would like to only give them object files for the files I do not want them to edit.

How can I modify my Makefile in order to accomplish that?

Comment: Any specific reasons to use make file and not cmake? The solution is to just create a static or a shared lib from your source and hand over the headers to your clients.

Comment: Invoke make just asking for the specific object file: make myroutine.obj.  If there are multiple *.obj files, wrap the list in a *.CMD file.

Comment: @cplusplusrat Can I create a library file that contain a main function? This is an application that contains a bunch of callback functions we would like to give this application to someone to fill out the callback functions so it makes sense to let them develop their part of the code as a shared library which we would load from within the main application.

Comment: The problem is that they might need to use some of the functions from the main application which we really do not want to create into libraries for them to use. We prefer to make this as simple as possible by compiling the project once keep the object files that are created from each source file and let them edit only the files they intend to use this way they can compile the two files they will edit then the linker would like all the object files together and create the final binary.